# How To Associate Specific Product Item ID aka Name With An InApp Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Imagine a world of widgets where each widget has a unique name / identifier. For example, ABC.

I need to deliver specific content (ABC content) that they bought based on that unique identifier after payment has been confirmed by Apple.

Here's an example: They purchased a Widget, but I need to know what the specific identifier aka name of the widget was that they bought in order to get them the right widget content. Each widget has a unique identifier / name that comes from the server. There are billions of uniquely named widgets.

Ideally, I would send supplemental information with the transaction to Apple so that when the transaction success notification comes back I know exactly which Widget (such as ABC) has been bought.

Is there a way to send supplemental information that is returned to me later or do I need to manage my own queue of product purchases where each purchase has the specific name / identifier of the product? If I have to manage my own collection of attempted Widget purchases, what is good practice on doing that? Do I store an NSMutableArray of SKPaymentTransaction objects to look up later?

(BTW, there are three different kinds of boxes. Each different kind of box has a different cost and thus productIdentifier.) However, only 1 kind of box requires the named Widget feature.

Thanks!

BTW, I studied this documentation and what it links to a lot: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, the answer is to track your own specific product information.

In the context of widgets, have your own queue (NSMutableArray) of specific widgets (or just widget names if that's all you need). This custom Widget queue is referred to after getting the green light (verified receipt) from apple.

In other words, put Widget on your own Widget queue, get green light from Apple, get Widget off of queue, and do what you need to do to deliver content.

All of this is much easier if the management of the custom queue and the interactions with Apple's Store Kit is done by a class called TransactionBroker (or whatever name you wish).